# xfrac package together with cabin package (sf font)

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, xfrac

Can't I use [`cabin`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cabin) and `xfrac` together? `nicefrac` package works by the way.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\sfrac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

### Error Message

```
 Missing character: There is no / in font Cabin-Regular-tlf-ts1! LaTeX
 Font Info: Font shape `OT1/Cabin-TLF/m/n' will be (Font) scaled to
 size 0.0pt on input line 8. ! Improper `at' size (0.0pt), replaced by
 10pt.
```

### Workaround

Here's my real life example using the `nicefrac` package:

[image]

### Update

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{\familydefault}{text}
 {
  slash-symbol-font=ptm
 }

\begin{document}
\section*{cabin}
\sfrac{1}{2} 
\nicefrac{1}{2}

\section*{ECFAugie}
\ECFAugie
%\sfrac{1}{2} % <-- Problem lies here :)
\nicefrac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Final Solution

Based on `egreg`'s answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{\familydefault}{text}
{
    slash-symbol-font=ptm
}

\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{fau}{text}
{
    slash-symbol-font=ptm
}

\begin{document}
\section*{cabin}
\sfrac{1}{2} 
\nicefrac{1}{2}

\section*{ECFAugie}
\ECFAugie
\sfrac{1}{2} 
\nicefrac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, there is no `/` (solidus) in the font, so the package sets a zero dimensional box and cannot compute the required size for the font.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. `cabin` does not support math I guess. But `nicefrac` produces a proper output with a `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message comes from the fact that no “solidus” exists in the TS1 encoded version of the Cabin font, so the box used for measuring turns out to have zero height and the following computations give a wrong result.

You can add a substitute, as shown in the manual for `xfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{\familydefault}{text}
 {
  slash-symbol-font=ptm
 }

\begin{document}

\sfrac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For `emerald`, note that it has

```
\newcommand\ECFAugie{\fontfamily{fau}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
```

so you should be able to get away with

```
\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{fau}{text}
 {
  slash-symbol-font=ptm
 }
```

(Cannot test as it requires nonfree fonts.)

Comment: Damn. I also use `emerald` package and `{\ECFAugie \sfrac{1}{2}}` in the real document (I wanted to keep the example minimal). Still the same error. But with the code that I provided in the MWE it works.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You have to declare an instance also for the Emerald font.

Comment: Can I update the question and you update the answer? Have to leave in 2 min. Will reply later.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, of course. I cannot guess at your code, so please be specific.

Comment: Done. See you later.

Comment: Thanks. The font is at least part of MiKTeX. I will test it later.

Comment: It works! I updated the question with your solution. I just copied your code (now there are two `\DeclareInstance{xfrac}`) and it worked.